# Test like ANOVA but allowing for multiple group membership

Tags: anova, categorical-data

I have data where each individual tested has a score on a single common outcome variable, but may belong to multiple groups (in this case, sports teams - some only play football, others play soccer AND football, for example). What's the best test for comparing means on the outcome variable across the sports?